# .getJSON.done() function doesn't call else .fail() is always called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have written html page which takes an input from user and on click submit calls a javascript function. The html page is given below:

```
<body>
        <input type="text" id="input_"/>
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Get tweets"/>
        <div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

and the javascript is:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
        $.getJSON("tweets.php?q="+$('#input_').val())
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
    });
```

the url in .getJSON is actually localhost/tweets.php?q=(userInput) but the url doesnt return anything in getJSON.done function however if i use .fail(err) and display err on console it prints the returned data on console. Also if I manually open for example: localhost/tweets.php?q=mkx on browse the data is displayed on browser. I cant seem to find any problem in the code. The tweets.php file is below:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
                $getfield = '?q=%23'.$_GET["q"];
                $requestMethod = 'GET';
                $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
                echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                             ->performRequest(true);
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: what does the output look like when you open in browser? is it valid json?

Comment: yes it is valid json like this: {"statuses":[{"metadata":{"iso_language_code":"en","result_type":"recent"},"created_at":"Fri Jul 24 17:36:47 +0000 2015","id":624634345051979776,"id_str":"624634345051979776",...

Comment: please check if the server or your your php app returns a valid json format response.

Comment: need to inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for more clues...status, url, response body etc

Comment: is the response type `application/json`  ??

Comment: @EkanshRastogi won't matter much, getJSON expects to parse json and it will even with content type headers as text/html

Comment: Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html>
↵<html>
↵ <head>
↵  <title>Tweets<… invalid url parameter."}]} 
↵ </body>
↵</html>  ", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}   this response is visible on console if i replace .done with .fail

Comment: looks like path is wrong or something , or you have other output in that php file .... only thing it can send back is one json block. Is clearly returning html OR   value of `$('#input_').val()` is invalid or it needs to be url_encoded

Comment: header('Content-type: application/json'); I used this header before echo $tweets but no success

Comment: problem solved..thanks guys...i was using html tags and scripts in php file which were altering the json response